# Checking if any of the fields is null in a row

Tags: php

I'm developing an application in which I need to  click if any of the fields in a row is empty or not. If any of the fields is empty, then the variable `$flag` should be 1, other wise zero.
I have written till here, but I'm not sure what to do next to check if each and every field is null/empty or not.

```
public function profileComplete($email)
{
    global $conn;
    $flag=0;
    try
    {
        $s = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from users where emailid = : email");
        $s->bindParam(":email",$email);
        $s->execute();
        $s->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        while($row = $s->fetch())
        {

        }
    }
}
```

How should I code to make it work according to the requirements?
All suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: there is no shortcut. you'll have to do `where field1 is null or field2 is null or field3 is null .... or fieldn is null`.

Comment: @MarcB: That's obviously not true. Just set `$flag` to 1 inside that loop whenever there is any non-NULL element inside `$row`...

Comment: So the whole global thing, is that a design flaw?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: and how do you propose testing all of those returned fields for nullness without testing each one?

Comment: Please define what needs to be treated as empty, see my answer or a list of values treated as empty(),

Comment: you probably shouldn't do the try with out the catch, you may get errors and never see them, the purpose of try/catch is to give the application a way to recover it there is an error, not to hide the errors.

Comment: @MarcB: You can test each one without writing every single possible array key out by hand. Heard of a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id go with array filter and count the row, to avoid the inner loop.

```
$num_fields = 8; //should know this before hand but you could compare $row and $_row below but it would be more expensive to run.
while($row = $s->fetch()){
    $_row = array_filter($row); //removes all empty elements
    if(count($_row) != $num_fields){
       //some fields are empty
    } 
}
```

if you consider 0 empty this will be fine. - note -  that empty() will also treat 0 as empty, if you need the 0 as not empty you can use a custom function in array_filter for the callback with the === 0 strict equality or !== 0 to check for that.

empty() treats these values as empty - and will return TRUE on them.

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   public function profileComplete($email)
  {
   global $conn;
   $flag=0;
  try
   {
    $s = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from users where emailid = : email");
    $s->bindParam(":email",$email);
    $s->execute();
    $s->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    while($row = $s->fetch())
    {
          foreach($row as $r){
            if(is_null($r) || $r==''){
              $flag=1;
            }
          }
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row = $s->fetch())
{
    foreach($row as $val) 
    {
        if(empty($val)) { $flag = 1; }
    }
}
```

'empty()' assumes you want to catch null, false, empty strings, and zeros. If you don't want to catch zeros/false, use `if(is_null($val) || $val == '') { $flag = 1; }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this although I haven't checked the output. Hope it helps you! :)

```
while($row = $s->fetch()){
     foreach($row as $rowval){
          if($rowval == null || empty($rowval)){
             $flag=1;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: null is empty(), the check really should be (empty($rowval) && !== 0) if the OP has Boolean 0 fields or fields such as a price total that my be 0 and should not be considered empty.